# .htaccess on specific filetypes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some magic stuff in my htaccess. It works very well but I don't know how

```
RewriteRule ^[^_+/]. index.php
```

I think it says that all requests should go through index.php no matter which directory the visitor ask for. So far so good. However images, css files, js files etc should of course not be parsed in index.php. Can I exclude certain directories from the above rule? Like /img, /css and /js

Other suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid requests to certain paths by using a simple RewriteCond...

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^img
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^js
# or alternatively just
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !^(css|img|js)
```

Comment: Thanks man! Works like a charm. I had to add a slash prior to the directory name though.

Answer (score 4):

you can exclude *existing* files and directories

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

by placing this before your rule

Comment: I guess it'll work. However I would feel more secure with deny all and have exception from that with specific paths. I'll use your solution in the meantime