# Tried all jquery methods and js to check for file exist but all doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, exists

Tried all jquery methods and js to check for file exist but all doesn't work all give me that any file that exist or doesn't on my server / with my domain that it does exist although some dont... idk why it say that all does although they dont?!!! maybe something wrong with my server? idk :( i need help tried all of that

```
$.get('http://MyUrl/file.wav')
.done(function() { 
    alert('exists');

}).fail(function() { 
    alert('does not exist');

})
```

&

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://MyUrl/file.wav', //or your url
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data){
    alert('exists');
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert('does not exist');
  },
})
```

&

```
    function doesFileExist(urlToFile)
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://MyUrl/file.wav', false);
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status == "404") {
            //return false;
    console.log('not exist');
        } else {
            //return true;
            console.log('file with that name exists exists');

        }}
```

&

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://MyUrl/file.wav',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists

    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
      console.log('file with that name exists exists');
    }
});
```

idk what else i do really but it frustrate me that it always give me exists or true no matter file exists or not.....

Comment: are you trying to check for the existence of file on server from client browser with js?

Comment: yes. i want to know if exists or not

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using rewrite rules on your server? If yes, most likely your server is rewriting your requests for non-existing files and you are getting response from some script which handles requests. Did you check response from your server? For example, open `developer tools` in `chrome browser` and then open the url of non-existing file in chrome, what do you see in `network` tab of developer tools? If you are always getting `200` http response, you will need to change your `rewrite conditions` or modify your script to check for file existence and send back `404` if file does not exist.

Comment: i am getting 200 and 302s only and 302 means found.. how to change rewrite conditions or modify my script can u be more specific. i am owner of server so i can do anything even internally but idk what exactly u mean please be more clear and detailed cuz this my first time to get such issue

Comment: There are many possible answers on how to do it, depending on which server are you using (apache, nginx, ...), which server side language/framework/application, do you want to check only for files of certain type (for example only wav, mp3, avi,...), do you want to check only specific subdirectory, etc.?
Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482969/htaccess-on-specific-filetypes?rq=1 or search internet for something like `mod_rewrite tutorial` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route for `ajax`

Server side:

```
echo json_encode(new Array(exists => file_exists(filePath + $_POST['filename]));
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://MyUrl/fileexists.php', // new route
    type:'POST', // post data
    data: { filename: 'new.wav' }, // data to post
    dataType: 'json', // returned data type
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function(resp)  {
        //file exists?
      console.log('file with that name exists exists?' + resp.exists);
    }
});
```

Comment: hey man i like ur code. its the most reliable one with my situation but it always give me no exist... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("/path/to/file/")
.always(function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // if file does not exist, or `error` , log `textStatus`, `errorThrown`
  if (textStatus !== "success") console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);  
  // else, log response `data`
  else console.log(data);
});
```